# How to import an updated module without restarting session in Rodeo?

Tags: python, rodeo

In Rodeo, if my script A imports a module B, and I make modifications to module B after running script A once, I have to restart the session in order for my script A to read the updated module B, in the process wiping my workspace and namespace clean. Is there a way to iterate quickly on importing B into A in a less disruptive way?

Answer (score 2):

I do this with `exec`.

```
exec(open("Path/To/Script/A.py").read())
```

Also, Rodeo is undergoing rapid development so it's helpful if you put your version number in the question.  I recommend checking out the latest version, 1.4.9, downloadable from the [Rodeo project page on github](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo).  But keep an eye out for updated versions as they're coming in almost daily at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import moduleB
reload (moduleB)
```

after new edits in ModuleB you can just use **`reload(moduleB)`**